# instance variable in blocks

Tags: ruby

How to pass an instance variable as an *argument* to a block?

This doesn't work in Ruby 1.9 (**formal argument cannot be an instance variable**).

```
awesome do |foo, @bar|
  puts 'yay'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 cases here which could be relevant:

- Instance variable of the definer of the block that references the instance variable (in the example the usage of `awesome2`.
- Instance variable of the definer of the block that gives the instance variable as argument to the receiver (no chance to give it as argument to the block). This is usage of `awesome`.
- Instance variable of the user of the block that gives the instance variable as argument to the block. This is usage of `awesome3`.

So lets try to implement both examples to see them. The example is lengthy, the relevant lines are:

- `awesome` gets the instance variable as argument, which is then used by the receiver in the call of the block
- `awesome2` gets no instance variable, it is bound by `Sender#use_in_block`. No chance for the receiver to change that binding.
- `awesome3` gets the instance variable of the sender, but uses its own instance variable for calling the block

So depending on what you want to reach, one of the three is the better solution.

```
class Sender
  attr_accessor :send_var
  def call_a_block(var)
    rec = Receiver.new(5)
    @my_var = var
    res = rec.awesome(@my_var) do |arg1|
      arg1 + 3
    end 
    res2 = rec.awesome3(@my_var) do |arg1|
      arg1 + 3
    end
    p "Result of calling awesome with: 3 and #{@my_var} is #{res}"
    p "Result of calling awesome3 with: 3 and #{@my_var} is #{res2}"
  end
  def use_in_block(var)
    rec = Receiver.new(6)
    @my_var = var
    res = rec.awesome2 do
      4 + @my_var
    end
    p "Result of calling awesome2 with: 4 and #{@my_var} is #{res}"
  end
end

class Receiver
  attr_accessor :rec_var
  def initialize(var)
    @rec_var = var
  end
  def awesome(arg1)
    res = yield(arg1)
    res * 2
  end
  def awesome3(arg1)
    res = yield(@rec_var)
    res * 2
  end
  def awesome2
    res = yield
    res * 2
  end
end

s = Sender.new
s.call_a_block(7)
s.call_a_block(20)
s.use_in_block(7)
s.use_in_block(20)
```

Results are:

```
c:\Temp>ruby call.rb

"Result of calling awesome with: 3 and 7 is 20"
"Result of calling awesome3 with: 3 and 7 is 16"
"Result of calling awesome with: 3 and 20 is 46"
"Result of calling awesome3 with: 3 and 20 is 16"
"Result of calling awesome2 with: 4 and 7 is 22"
"Result of calling awesome2 with: 4 and 20 is 48"
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Others may want to read this [intro](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html) as well. My problem wasn't this, so I've asked a new question.

Comment: Also, this is a solution: `[1,2,3].each {|bar| @bar=bar }` taken from [here](http://boga.wordpress.com/2008/04/15/ruby-19-porting-notes/).

Answer (score 4):

Ruby 1.9 makes block parameters local to the block. This also means that block parameters can no longer be global or instance variables. You can use closures for your purposes:

```
@foo = 10
1.times do |i|
  puts @foo
end
# => "10"
```

**UPDATE**
Instead of using instance variables, local variable can help you:

```
foo = 10
1.times do |i|
  puts foo
end
# => "10"
```

In such cases, you won't get problems related to code execution inside different context.

Comment: I can't do that. That's why I was confused! Take a look at my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107584/cant-access-activerecord-mutators-in-a-block).

Comment: Ok, got it. I've updated my post and answered on your question.