# can't access ActiveRecord mutators in a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, prawnto

I am inside a Rails controller and I am trying to access my instance variable in a block:
This gives an error saying that "no method field1 for Nil":

```
Prawn::Document.generate("hello.pdf") do
  @model.field1
end
```

However, if I do this, then it works:

```
my_model = @model
Prawn::Document.generate("hello.pdf") do
  my_model.field1
end
```

Could this have something to do with ActiveRecord accessors or instance variables in a block?

Comment: This question should answer yours, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150483/instance-variable-not-available-inside-a-ruby-block

Comment: Thanks, I think this thread has better answers though :P I don't think it would make sense to merge these two threads into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because code inside block is executed in context of Prawn::Document object. Let's go inside this code:

```
module Prawn
  class Document
    def self.generate(filename,options={},&block)
      pdf = new(options,&block)
      pdf.render_file(filename)
    end

    def initialize(options={},&block)
      if block
        block.arity < 1 ? instance_eval(&block) : block[self]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, `block` is executed with `Document` object as `self`. It try to find @model as instance variable of `self`, can't do this and return `nil`. If you use local variable `model`, you get help of closures and your code is working properly

Comment: Also, is there a short way of turning an instance variable into a variable in Ruby without wasting a line like I did with `my_model = @model`?

Answer (score 3):

This kind of problem appears when a block is being executed in a different context, usually through a `instance_eval`. So let's check the code:

```
#lib/prawn/document.rb: Document#initialize    
if block
  block.arity < 1 ? instance_eval(&block) : block[self]
end
```

There you have your `instance_eval`, and you can also see the solution: pass a block that accepts the document as argument and you'll now be able to access the instance variables as usual:

```
Prawn::Document.generate("hello.pdf") do |doc|
  @my_model.field1
end
```